# Skipping nil values and keep executing the rest of code

Tags: ios, swift

I have a code like following:

```
for index in 0..<parts.count {
let title = parts[index].title
titleArray.append(title)
}
```

I have an array called parts. And some parts have titles and some do not have. So if I run the code, it always fails since there will be nil value at some index.

How would I structure this to just append existing title? I was thinking of using guard let but I wasn't sure how to implement it.

Comment: not possible to use if-else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is an `if let` statment for checking if the title is `nil` or not, like this:

```
for index in 0..<parts.count {
    if let title = parts[index].title {
         titleArray.append(title)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like (code typed directly into browser so may have typos)

```
for part in parts {
    titleArray.append(part.title ?? valueToUseForNilTitle)
}
```

You could also skip the nil entries entirely with

```
for part in parts where part.title != nil {
    ...
}
```

Or if you want to get a bit fancier

```
titleArray = parts.flatMap { $0.title }
```

Comment: Fixed :) forgot the parts themselves weren't optional

Answer (score 2):

```
titleArray += parts.flatMap { $0.title }
```

This should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much more easily by enumerating the array...

```
for part in parts where part.title != nil {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It throws an error at part.title since that value is already nil for some part. any thoughts to improve this?

Comment: @Kahsn did you add the where bit to the loop? The where bit makes sure each part.title is not nil

Comment: it was complaining part.title  is nil. Which I do not really get since there is "where" used. Not sure.